# Use an integer in a pandas dataframe column to extract a specific value from a list inside another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with a list inside a column, and another column with a specific integer value for that row. I want to use this integer value to extract a specific value from the list inside the other column:

df:

```
    list                                         val
1   ['mohamed', 'adam', 'paul', 'dave']           3
2   ['dave', 'fred']                              0
3   ['john', 'dave', 'jane']                      1
4   ['dave']                                      0
```

this was created by:

```
df = df.loc[df['unsplit_list'].str.contains('dave')]
df['list'] = df['unsplit_list'].str.split('|')
df['val'] = df['list'].apply(lambda lst: [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if 'dave' in x][0])
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(int)
```

when i try to obtain the value for dave out of my list, it comes up with an error:

```
df['list'].str[df['val']]

>>
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

however if i did:

```
df['list'].str[df[1]]
```

then i would be able to obtain the value in the list using this integer. How can I get this value i want out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['name'] = [row[0][row[1]] for ix, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['list'][x['value']], axis=1)
```